# Subscribe to topic with multiple levels in Config file?

Tags: mqtt

I am trying to subscribe to multiple topic levels in the configuration file and the aim is whenever I launch the MQTT, the broker has those topics, after which when I enter a wild card it string compare and checks if the topic is on the broker and if yes it extracts the data and if not it jumps to the next branch level

I have tried to write a level topic tree but dont know how to subscribe in the config file, as   I am most sure if mosquitto.subscribe will work there or not

Below shows the snippet of the topic tree,

```
  tree is the root node,
  sub_branch = tree/sub_branch;
  sub_branch_1 = tree/sub_branch_1;
  branch_1 = tree/branch/branch_1;
  branch_2 = tree/branch/branch_2;
```

After launch, the topics are on the broker and I use wildcard 
    tree/#;
this should give me data for all the branches
and if  topic =  tree/ranch; its an error(wrong topic) and ask for the next one

Any help is much much appreciated!

Comment: Removed the C++ tag as it has no relevance to the question

Comment: What do you mean by "launch the MQTT"? Do you mean start the broker or a MQTT client?

Comment: What config file are you talking about?

Comment: by launch I meant starting the mqtt broker, and the config file is the mqtt config file

Comment: Again what is the "mqtt config file" do you mean for a client or the broker?

Comment: by config file I mean the one for broker, the main idea is I can define topic levels inside the config file and when I publish message it string compare and see if the topic exists, if yes it output the message if not it moves to the next level

Comment: Read my answer, you DO NOT pre-configure topics

Answer (score 0):

You do NOT configure topics on the broker, the broker has no knowledge of what topics a client might publish messages to or what topics a client might subscribe to (apart from in any Access Control Lists).

As far as the broker is concerned topics don't exist until a client publishes a message, at which point it does the following things in order:

1. Checks the ACL for that user/client if one exists to see if there is a pattern matching the incoming topic and accepts or discards the message if there is a match
2. Assuming it accepts the message it then searches the list of topic patterns for all subscribed clients.
3. If there is a match for a client it checks that client's/user's ACL to see if there is a match and if allowed sends that message to the client.